# The word "but" with no noun

Tags: nouns

Is this sentence legit?
For example, `Did you watch the movie but forgot the ending?` or should I say `Did you watch the movie but you forgot the ending?`

Comment: Did you watch the movie but **forget** the ending. Present tense did goes with both.

Answer (score 1):

`but` is a conjunction. Therefore, there are two sentences here:

`Did you watch the movie?` and `Did you forget the ending?` In both these cases, `you` is the noun, so there is indeed a noun present, and joining them together with `but` will work in both cases:

`Did you watch the movie but you **forget** the ending?` correct

`Did you watch the movie but **forget** the ending?` also correct

Comment: Did you watch the movie but you forget the ending? //is not correct.